# Sending email exception in play 2.0

Tags: java, playframework, playframework-2.0

I am using play 2.0 for a project and i am trying to send email to user. I use this plugin [https://github.com/typesafehub/play-plugins/tree/master/mailer].

In my Build.scala I added

```
 "com.typesafe" %% "play-plugins-mailer" % "2.0.4"
```

and  in conf/play.plugins

```
 1500:com.typesafe.plugin.CommonsMailerPlugin
```

In my conf/application.conf I have the settings

```
 smtp.host=smtp.gmail.com
 smtp.port=25
 smtp.ssl=true
 smtp.tls=false
 smtp.username="test@gmail.com"
 smtp.password="xxxxxxx"
```

My controller action is

```
 public static Result sendEmail(String recipt, String title, String sender ){
    MailerAPI mail = play.Play.application().plugin(MailerPlugin.class).email();
      mail.setSubject(SUBJECT);
      mail.addRecipient(recipt);
      mail.addFrom(sender);
      String body = views.html.teams.mailBody.render(recipt, title, sender).body();
      mail.sendHtml(body);
      return ok();
 }
```

I get the following error

```
[EmailException: Sending the email to the following server failed : smtp.gmail.com:25]
```

What I am doing wrong. Any help will be highly appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The SMTP configuration for Gmail is different (secured with TLS enabled on port 587).

Try with this config:

```
smtp.host=smtp.gmail.com
smtp.port=587
smtp.ssl=true
smtp.tls=true
smtp.username="test@gmail.com"
smtp.password="xxxxxxx"
```

Answer (score 4):

Just wasted an hour on this, this worked:

```
smtp.user="test@gmail.com"
smtp.password="xxxxxxx"
```

**smtp.user not smtp.username**